# Available filters for client.get_products function in Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to develop a python script that gets different parameters of any AWS service (for EC2 e.g., those parameters would be operating system, billing type etc.). Where can I find a listing of all the available Filters that can be used with the get_products function in boto3 for each different supported Service?

Thanks in advance,
Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no direct API or doc available for getting all the attributes. At least I didnt find any.

What you can do is combine various API calls:

1. You can use [DescribeServices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_pricing_DescribeServices.html)
   , you get all the `attributes` of the all the services or if you want to have for one particular you can provide the name. Boto3 call [describe_services](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/pricing.html#Pricing.Client.describe_services)

> Returns the metadata for one service or a list of the metadata for all services

2. Then you need to use [GetAttributeValues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_pricing_GetAttributeValues.html) to determine the possible values of the attributes. Boto3 call [get_attribute_values](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/pricing.html#Pricing.Client.get_attribute_values)
3. And finally depending on the attributes collected in the earlier step you can build a filter for [get_producs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/pricing.html#Pricing.Client.get_products)